# Pass args to a jar launched by a Kubernetes cron job

Tags: java, kubernetes, cron

I have deployed a Kubernetes cron job that executes a java jar.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: my-cron-job
  namespace: test
  labels:
    app: my-cron-job
    release: dev
    tiers: backend
spec:
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: app_name
              image: docker-image
              command: ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
              args:
                - |
                  java -jar /app.jar
              env:
                - name: USER
                  valueFrom:
                    secretKeyRef:
                      name: secrets
                      key: user
                - name: PASSWORD
                  valueFrom:
                    secretKeyRef:
                      name: secrets
                      key: pwd
              resources:
                requests:
                  memory: "20Mi"
                  cpu: "50m"
                limits:
                  memory: "20Mi"

  schedule: "0 0 * * *"
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
```

For testing, I'd like to execute this cron job as a one time job while passing certain args to the java jar.

I was able to run the one time job using :

```
kubectl create job my-cron-job-manual --from=cronjob/my-cron-job
```

but couldn't find a way to pass any dynamic args to the jar in a similar way to this :

```
java -Dtest_arg=XXXXX -jar /app.jar
```

Can you please point me to directions I can investigate ? Maybe I'm missing something with Kubernetes / cron jobs ?

Thank you.

Comment: Firstly: *java -jar /app.jar* You're aware that's addressing a jar in the root of the file system? It should almost certainly not be there. Let's say it can go in your home dir. It might be worth an experiment of `java "$@" -jar /home/someone/app.jar`

Comment: Not knowing the software you're using though, I don't know that script would get the parameters in my example